# Splitting a column title by delimiter in R

Tags: r, split, delimiter

I currently have a df that I distilled and reorganized using the reshape2 package. My new df now contains some columns that have names that are delimited by an "_", like so:

```
Location   Type   Time   DO_ResultValue   ENT_ResultValue   TEMP_WATER_ResultValue
CHE008     Out    7:58   3.19 mg/l        <10 MPN/100ml     13 deg C
CHEFENCO   Out    6:53   8.54 mg/l        34 MPN/100ml      12.7 deg C
REVx2      In     7:19   6.72 mg/l        127 MPN/100ml     13.6 deg C
```

The "_ResultValue" resulted when I melted my df and then cast variables within "ResultValue" into their own columns. Also note that TEMP_WATER already has one delimiter within it. The output I'm looking for is.

```
Location   Type   Time   DO               ENT               TEMP_WATER
CHE008     Out    7:58   3.19 mg/l        <10 MPN/100ml     13 deg C
CHEFENCO   Out    6:53   8.54 mg/l        34 MPN/100ml      12.7 deg C
REVx2      In     7:19   6.72 mg/l        127 MPN/100ml     13.6 deg C
```

I need to remove the "_ResultValue" from the headings such that I can match the headings with a user input list of required headings and reorder the columns to produce an output table. Therefore, I can't use some sort of colnames() function and rename them manually b/c their names will vary with each run of the code based on user inputs.

Help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `sub` to work on `names()` values. It will skip over the strings that do not have that extension:

```
names(dfrm) <- sub("_ResultValue", "", names(dfrm) )
```

Answer (score 3):

These two functions can help you along.

```
> unlist(strsplit(x, "_ResultValue"))
[1] "Location"   "Type"       "Time"       "DO"         "ENT"        "TEMP_WATER"
> gsub("_ResultValue", "", x)
[1] "Location"   "Type"       "Time"       "DO"         "ENT"        "TEMP_WATER"
```

Comment: Thanks, @RomanLustrik for the quick response! I found that this worked well and was adjustable code to other purposes.